# Change event not triggering in Angular 7 DOM testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, dom, jestjs, angular7

I'm trying to DOM test this simple component:

I'm trying to check that (change) is triggering onChange, and thus I need to fire `change`.

Simple, right? Wrong.

I tried using Angular functions, and native DOM API, but I still can't trigger the function programmatically.

Here's my test:

```js
  it('should emit filter events', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'onChange');

        const input = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
        input.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {target: {value: 'Building UUID'}}))

        fixture.detectChanges()

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            expect(component.onChange).toHaveBeenCalled()
    });

  });
```

```html
<div>
  <input
        #input
    type="text"
    (change)="onChange"
    placeholder="Search by DeviceID or building"
  />
  <a class="reset" (click)="onReset()"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: shouldn't onChange be onChange() in html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated, it should be `onChange()` instead of `onChange`... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `fakeAsync`

```
 it('should emit filter events', fakeAsync(() => {
    const spyOnChange = spyOn(component, 'onChange');

    const input = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
    input.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {target: {value: 'Building UUID'}}))

    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(spyOnChange).toHaveBeenCalled()

  }));
```